# Symfony session avoid _sf2_attributes

Tags: php, session, symfony

Apparently every key I save to a Symfony2 session goes under a subkey:

```
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
```

Will result in:

```
array('_sf2_attributes' => array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

This is a problem because I'm building an application that interacts with legacy code. I want to use Symfony's session handler but I want old parts of the app to be able to read from `$_SESSION`. In other words, I want

```
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
```

and

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

to have the same effect.

I didn't see any [configuration option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html) to achieve this. I use a specific session handler which I set to

```
session:
    handler_id: my_app.session_handler
```

So it won't be a problem that Symfony uses a different session name. The only solution I can think of is creating a new session handler class around my customer session handler (`my_app.session_handler`) that checks if the application tries to access `_sf2_attributes` but I think it's extremely ugly and I'm not even sure if would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not only the handler that you have to implement on your own, but it also should be your `SessionStorage`.

By default, Symfony2 uses `NativeSessionStorage`. You should be looking for the method [`loadSession()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L416-L432). As you can see, it initializes a session with the `$key` received from `getStorageKey()`, which is initialized with `_sf2_attributes` here - in the [`AttributeBag`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Attribute/AttributeBag.php#L36-L39)

Let me know if you have problems injecting custom session storage.

Comment: Thank you. I checked this option but I'm not sure this is the best I can do. Now I'm fairly familiar with the Session API, but because the whole system works with variable references it seems to be pretty difficult to achieve what I want.

Comment: Finally came up with this: https://gist.github.com/tcz/9756112 Ugly as hell but works. I use it in the session config `storage_id` key which is not very well documented. Thanks!

Comment: I have similar issue but this time with Memcached , in my config file I have handler_id:  session.handler.memcached
which is defined in services , but my problem is session don't get stored to memcached server using the $session->set('foo', 'bar');
any help ?